# Typescript recursive type doesn't seem to be resolved correctly

Tags: typescript, recursion

I would like to know if there are some pitfalls with typescript recursive types that I would not be aware of.

Here is my problem.

Here is a simplified reproduction code of my problematic recursive type :

```js
import { U } from 'ts-toolbelt';
import { Types as MongooseTypes } from 'mongoose';

export type Id = MongooseTypes.ObjectId;

export interface Idable {
  _id: Id;
}

export type _TransformEntityToInput<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends '_id'
    ? T[K] | undefined
    : // WARNING : We don't want to go inside Id even if it actually contains _id field.
    T[K] extends Id | U.Nullable<Id>
    ? T[K]
    : // ----
    T[K] extends Array<infer ArrayType>
    ? Array<_TransformEntityToInput<ArrayType>>
    : T[K] extends U.Nullable<Array<infer ArrayType>>
    ? U.Nullable<Array<_TransformEntityToInput<ArrayType>>>
    : // ----
    T[K] extends object
    ? // We only go inside if it's an object that has _id and is not of Id type
      T[K] extends Idable
      ? _TransformEntityToInput<T[K]>
      : T[K]
    : // ----
    T[K] extends U.Nullable<infer O>
    ? // We only go inside if it's an object that has _id and is not of Id type
      O extends object
      ? O extends Idable
        ? U.Nullable<_TransformEntityToInput<O>>
        : U.Nullable<O>
      : T[K]
    : // ----
      T[K];
};

export type TransformEntityToInput<T extends object> = _TransformEntityToInput<T>;

class MembershipPerson {
  constructor(obj: MembershipPerson) {
    this._id = obj._id;
    this.foo = obj.foo
  }

  _id: Id
  foo: string
}

class Person {
    constructor(obj: Person) {
    this._id = obj._id;
    this.memberships = obj.memberships
  }

  _id: Id
  memberships?: MembershipPerson[]
}

class MembershipPersonInput {
  constructor(obj: MembershipPersonInput) {
    this._id = obj._id;
    this.foo = obj.foo
  }

  _id?: Id
  foo: string
}

class PersonInput {
    constructor(obj: PersonInput) {
    this._id = obj._id;
    this.memberships = obj.memberships
  }

  _id?: Id
  memberships?: MembershipPersonInput[]
}


const someFunction = (input: TransformEntityToInput<Person>) => {
  if (input.memberships && input.memberships.length > 0) {
    // Here : (property) _id: MongooseTypes.ObjectId | undefined
    console.log(input.memberships[0]._id)
  }
}

const context = (input: PersonInput) => {
  // Here : Property '_id' is optional in type 'MembershipPersonInput' but required in type '_TransformEntityToInput<Omit<MembershipPerson, keyof Trackable>, keyof Trackable>'
  someFunction(input)
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVTgXzgMyhEcDkMAzgLQwQQA2ARgKaUz4DcAUKJLInACoCeYtInACGQgLIQAdgHMKRWnwFCM2XARBTZEecxYtaADw7wY-WnACSAEzgBeOBJlyFZogDoA8tQBWtAMYw1qz6RtDwwJIwtFCYwn7m1sLUlOYILHBwAPrAVgBcllasaHqGxnCmAlncUMKSRJjQIACikcCm3BAWkmAArjAAPNwAfHaI6XAA2gDScBFwANa0vBCYPAC6+TOGUZJWQvjZVvjjGQD8PNNrcAA+cD27tJgRtFYncPkA9B9wAOoAggAlAByFiBAHF3r9zFYpIQ4AB3WomCBwWSzOo5BI2WgAN1oklmqzaIgCPWElEovDgfikMGEESEhywwHoVjcb24lzg23xewKNxQbiBPQpSRS-WsQze505UzWb0+3xIypIHK5PN2Qj+UBqvH6EUw0Tg2t1iloUoyZ2NOuEesy1Vq9UaLRgbV4HS6vQGJttZqGFst+VlVw1fOQQpFlDFtH6Pr1BqNcb9Aat4eFouSMbj-XtNTqDSgzVa7U63T6sZt7rM-pTkK+cBVqstFzl3IMOz5EB8-hg0rg9Z+5iklNRKIZmMJs0YQlqcC7vgC5QAFsJ4CvGTkRLtZkJJBB4Ct+RVaG8MsG2x2hIlM6e4Odc46C0XXSXPeXg7WMkHLgr+0qVWqrahkIaaRtG+qSIaUBwB4tbnAOQ6SCOaLjlY5jAES05bnO3aLjAK5rqIWSbrUNjALu+5zqs1jlGYt4eBevJCPOPa3ucDHAQU0a3qmEYZuKD75s6xbuqWXr9LBn6BoK6ZRpmElSd+cq-vWja3sGRTBKUYS0ZUDpCYWLpuh6ZYDNwjGajhC4wCM9iCU6hkiSZ4nDMEfhRkQ4i0CAdBQEQS7AGAAAK0REFIYwZDSdQwFAPQBNAAAU875GI3m+f5gUhX5UgAJQRZa+HkW4TL2POxU5KwzaFe4DQoqVPhuLV4zFOMhz5NY4y1fkRAxRE0gsC17miEIWVhQSaTNlFPWxfFUBJT4+Sjbl+UZNV5U2PV3jrZVBUBe4IBpaFAVgEIm1uAdPlHYFRDNXoGRtQU4wXelx1EKcKWHX5x1LZIEzyoNHleZdX2ZaFUhvvAE3UlI01xeQc3JQ4n0ZcFYOSBDeVQ6te3raMZWHDt2NFbVeMNU1GQtfdOTvY9GRdXA019QNehDZ5cA-RDK3Q9FM3w-N3iLWjGNc2tJVWdtbxrc9V0naTW3SyDJ23a11Pta8GQKyjb0fcDKMc6Zf3MyzMPwGFB0AGL3AEwDhfYCURF6QZ5g5z7GWJ5Y-UMeW2CMUMYXA9umedyOvXAABkYfol6we669bgpDI+FwCMAAMmNvPWAAS0TmPkCVgDgAiwLweUPY4WjyGa7heNZNG3PcaFPJILxvFNVC0PHEDSIH0ea69Ewp2s605bdg0m9zUTtqMPd9IL2Xo6Z3u++MWc55CQWF9EpgEIc+A7nOYCulI5Lorp5j4Klseg-PEN79QfRwFAtAAI49MAT9kQSx47-pLtGa+pkJIgDaP0S+L1r5jQADQLCWIeB0fh5jRiGNAxYyxVjwMQZmIYxwMhm1oJbSQ1spAzxgCPNAQA)

In this example, `membership._id` can be `undefined` inside `someFunction`, yet i can't call this function with a PersonInput object :

```
Argument of type 'PersonInput' is not assignable to parameter of type '_TransformEntityToInput<Person>'.
  Types of property 'memberships' are incompatible.
    Type 'MembershipPersonInput[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Nullable<_TransformEntityToInput<MembershipPerson>[]>'.
      Type 'MembershipPersonInput[]' is not assignable to type 'Nullable<_TransformEntityToInput<MembershipPerson>[]>'.
        Type 'MembershipPersonInput' is not assignable to type '_TransformEntityToInput<MembershipPerson>'.
          Property '_id' is optional in type 'MembershipPersonInput' but required in type '_TransformEntityToInput<MembershipPerson>'.
```

I can't understand what is wrong in this piece of code.

Thank you for your help

Comment: ① Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when copied and pasted into a standalone IDE.  It should be minimal (ideally smaller than what you've got) and reproducible (no undeclared types like `Trackable`, `Nullable`, `Id`). ② Screenshots of IDEs are not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).

Comment: A [mre] needs to be included as plaintext in the question; a link to an IDE is a nice supplement but it doesn't suffice.  Please [edit] to put any such code here (I would do it but I don't have copyright on your externally-hosted code so I'm not going to touch that).  And again, it should be *minimal*, meaning that you should cut it down more, unless there's some reason why you need every bit of that to demonstrate the basic issue (it's okay for it to be less functional than whatever your use case is)

Comment: alright i'm about to update this content

Comment: Thanks; as it seems to depend on third-party libraries like ts-toolbelt and mongoose I probably won't engage here further; maybe someone else will. If you can produce a self-contained [mre] depending only on built-in stuff then I could take another look.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz - FWIW, what's in the code in the question does replicate the type error when copied and pasted into the TypeScript playground (since it supports imports), and the OP actually had edited the link they provided to link to the playground (instead of Code Sandbox) but forgot to fix the label on the link. I've done that now.

Comment: I'm not saying I can't import them, I'm just saying I'm not inclined to go chasing down issues involving third-party libraries.

Comment: thanks @jcalz, i understand. i'm going to simplify this code as much as possible and see if I can track this issue by myself. I'll come back with simplified use case and hopefully a solution. Sorry that my first question didn't respect standards. See you